# How to check if object or var is traversable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversable

How can I check the object or variable is traversable in Javascript or jQuery?

An object or a variable which is traversable must works in **for each** like `object.forEach()` and `$.each(object, callback)` in jQuery.

Actually I want to validate it then use it in for each loops.

**Update:**

The solution which I looking for is something like this:

```
if(is_traversable($var)) {
    $var.forEach(function(value, key) {
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

And you may give me an implementation of `is_traversable()` function.

Comment: There are no `for each` loops in JavaScript. Do you mean `for of`?

Comment: @Bergi There is forEach() method for arrays in Javascript. see more http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp

Comment: Sure, but that's just a method not a loop. And any object could have a method with that name. Or are you looking for arrays? Then you should ask for that.

Comment: @Bergi for (var property in object) {}

Comment: You can enumerate the properties of *all* objects like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For arrays, use [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) and for objects, you could first check not `null` and `typeof` is equal to `'object'` or `'function'`.

The wanted function for it:

```js
var isTraversable = o => Array.isArray(o)
     || o !== null && ['function', 'object'].includes(typeof o);

console.log(isTraversable());               // false
console.log(isTraversable(undefined));      // false
console.log(isTraversable(null));           // false
console.log(isTraversable(''));             // false
console.log(isTraversable(0));              // false
console.log(isTraversable('a'));            // false
console.log(isTraversable(42));             // false
console.log(isTraversable(/./));            // false
console.log(isTraversable([]));             // true
console.log(isTraversable([1]));            // true
console.log(isTraversable({}));             // true
console.log(isTraversable({ a: /./ }));     // true
console.log(isTraversable(function () {})); // true
console.log(isTraversable(() => true));     // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Similarly you can use typeof to detect the type. I believe arrays will list as objects though so use caution.

Comment: but `null` is an object and not iterable.

Comment: @NinaScholz null is not an object. Apparently `typeof null` is a bug in ecmascript when it outputs 'object'

Comment: Actually, there was a proposal to make `typeof null == "null"`, which was rejected: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3atypeof_null

Comment: This is not traversable : {} and [] , so you need to check also the length or if there is anything inside the object after it is the correct type with for( var p in o ) { return true; }. A string is also traversable when it is not empty. An object can be also a primitive type like a boolean or a number. These are not traversable.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Functions are traversable like any other object, but this solution returns false for them.

Answer (score 1):

`items` might be `Array` `Object`, `variable`

**Example**

items = [1,2,3,4]; **or** items = { name: 'abc', email: 'abc@xyz.com'}

```js
var items;

if (items && items instanceof Array) { // if Array
  items.forEach(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
} else if (items && items instanceof Object) { // if Object
  for (key in items) {
    console.log(items[keys]);
  }
} else { // if variable 
  console.log(items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following and create appropriate functions / validations:

```
var myArray = ["This is a test"];
var myObject = {"test" : "This is a test"};

if( Object.prototype.toString.call( myArray ) === '[object Array]' ) {
    alert( 'Array!' );
}

if( Object.prototype.toString.call( myObject ) === '[object Object]' ) {
    alert( 'Object!' );
}
```

Check out this one : [Object.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` and friends are implemented in a generic fashion, to be eligible, their argument

- must support the getter operator (`[]`)
- and must have a numeric `length` property.

That is, any string and any object with `.length` will work:

```
isIterable = x => x && !isNaN(x.length);
```

Note that `for..of` is different from `forEach`, it explicitly requires an argument to have `Symbol.iterator`.

```js
a = {
    length: 10,
    5: 555
};

[].forEach.call(a, x => console.log(x)); // fine

for(var x of a) console.log(x); // no way
```